# How can I animate a widget inside a SliverAppBar like this example?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

how is possibile to animate a widget inside a SliverAppBar like this example?

In this example "Pagamenti" text is animated when I scroll down.
I think this is achieved by a SliverAppBar with a FlexibleSpaceBar() but I am not able to do this.

Do I need a AnimatedPositioned widget?
Thanks.

[image]

Starting from here:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Floating App Bar';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        // No appbar provided to the Scaffold
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(title),
              leading: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 200,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('Pagamenti', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              ),
          ),
        ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item #$index')),
                childCount: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Floating App Bar';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        // No appbar provided to the Scaffold
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              //title: Text(title),
              leading: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 200,
              flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  print(constraints.maxHeight);
                  double actualHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
                  double val = (-(actualHeight - 80) / 144);
                  double actualText = ((actualHeight - 80) / 144) * 36 + 28;
                  print('actualText $actualText');
                  return Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      AnimatedAlign(
                        duration: Duration(microseconds: 1),
                        child: Text(
                          'Ciao',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: actualText),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment(val, 0.5),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item #$index')),
                childCount: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Solution gif](https://ibb.co/6HyX3p5)